# gnuserv as a web browser helper app

Tags: browser, emacs

I'm writing a program which is only ever going to run on my personal computer here.  It displays data in a web browser (usually Firefox), using one of those tiny-embedded-httpd libraries.  One of the things it will display, sometimes, is a filename (and line number) which I'll want to open in Emacs.

I'm thinking I can set up gnuserv to open text files (or even give it a dummy mime-type if I don't want all text files to open in emacs).

How can I get it to open this file at a particular line/column?  Gnuserv has a `[+line]` flag, but I don't know how to use it here.  I can't seem to find any documentation for Firefox helper apps that isn't out of date, or just plain wrong.  How does it run helper apps you specify?  Just "$app $filename"?

Since this is for my own personal use, anything is on the table at this point: Javascript, Greasemonkey, screwy HTML that will never work in IE, URLs that only make sense where the server=client, etc.

I've thought about trying to use `gnuclient`/`gnudoit`, and making the HTML page have a link to some elisp that loads the file and then goes to the correct line number, but I can't figure out how that would work: there's no way (probably a good thing, in general!) to click a link that runs some elisp on a webpage, when passed as a filename.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like what you have is a question on HTML, not on Emacs (as your problem is not doing something in Emacs but getting some other piece of software to invoke Emacs). If so, your question isn't getting the right kind of attention. Consider retagging it `html`, or `javascript`, or whatever makes sense (I don't know, I'm not familiar with these technologies). This may be more of an [application usage](http://superuser.com/) or perhaps [webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) question (but I'm not sure, check these sites' FAQ before posting).

Comment: Well, it's a question about getting a web browser and Emacs to communicate, so the answer may involve Emacs, or Firefox, or HTML, or Javascript, or shell scripting, or who knows what else.  I can certainly imagine a pure-Emacs solution to this (though I don't know if `gnuclient` can do exactly what I want).  But I will consider retagging later when I have more time to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your filename something like `filename:20` (filename:linenumber) and then wrap up an invocation of your `emacsclient` to expand that into a proper. I do this since tools like `grep` report things in this format. The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/364372).

Comment: emacsclient already supports line numbers by sending "emacsclient +20 filename", or is the problem that you can only supply a single argument from the browser?

Comment: In my case, it was because I wanted to cut/paste.

Comment: JSON: That's part of the problem: I don't know what the browser can do!  I've not been able to find any documentation that matches what I see in Firefox today.  Certainly if emacsclient supported "hello.c:20", or if Firefox supported passing multiple arguments to helper apps, either one would solve my problem.  The Emacs documentation suggests the former isn't possible, and I've no clue about the latter.